# Objective C Constants Usage NSString *const

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, notifications, constants

I am using the Parse AnyPic app to build an app. I do not understand the following usage:

```
NSString *const PAPAppDelegateApplicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification = @"com.parse.Anypic.appDelegate.applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification";
```

Why is com.parse.Anypic referenced in the above? Since Parse is no longer, what do I replace this with?

Why can't I use the following instead:

```
NSString *const PAPAppDelegateApplicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification = @"applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification";
```

Any explanation to help me understand what is needed to address replacing com.parse.Anypic

Answer (score 0):

I think the intent of this 3rd party framework is to prevent any name collisions with other notification names. They've prepended a common notation used to uniquely identify items. Its their domain name in reverse. If you don't use that it will conflict with an existing notification name and Parse wanted to differentiate the two for some reason.

Comment: So why is the word appDelegate also in the string. Is this like a path? I'm confused on how the name applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification is being used with the com.parse.Anypic.appDelegate. in front of it. How does the program know what to do with this? Sorry for the confusion as it does not make sense to me.

Comment: AppDelegate is probably just for more context on its use.

Comment: The program doesn't automatically use this, the developer would use this to listen for certain events if they were interested in this notification